# How to save a rails model with associated model at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When saving a model in Rails, I want to save another associated model along with it using the first model's ID.  IS there a way to do this in Rails 3?

*nevermind

model.build_other.  got it.  i'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but you can do it with a before_save callback. Say you have Model1 and Model2. Put the code below into app/models/model1.rb:

```
before_save :create_model2

def create_model2
  @model2 = Model2.new(params[:id])
  @model2.model1 = self
  @model2.save
end
```